# Discord Music bot throws this error randomly with apparently no provokation

Tags: node.js, discord.js, opus

I have coded a music bot on Discord using NodeJS and the `discord.js` npm package, that uses FFMPEG and `opusscript`. I run my bot on Heroku and this error occurs very frequently (it is too big to fit inside this question so I had to upload it as a Github Gist):

https://gist.github.com/PrittSpadeLord/f573d9080e6b65382bab8ba875587c6e

I have not been able to identify what causes this error, and as far as I know, it seems to be completely random. Sometimes it occurs immediately after I restart the bot, sometimes it may take up to even 10 minutes before this error occurs.

I have tried researching for this error, but since it doesnt give me a clear message of whats happening, I'm unable to get any reasonable information on what is causing this error. Some sources seem to suggest the problem is with `opusscript`.

**Relevant information:**

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myappname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gm": "^1.23.1",
    "google-it": "^1.5.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.2",
    "node-command-line": "^1.0.2",
    "node-random-name": "^1.0.1",
    "opusscript": "0.0.7",
    "ytdl-core": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate if I get some guidance on how I can fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

`opusscript` is not recommended by discord.js. Rather, you should use [@discordjs/opus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/opus).

Also `ytdl-core` is problematic, you should switch [ytdl-core-discord](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core-discord).

You will still run into issues with `ytdl-core-discord` like `Error: Too many redirects` but that is beyond our control. It is how `ytdl-core` itself has been coded on how it gets YouTube streams.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However I have been unable to get both `@discordjs/opus` and `node-opus` to work on my app. For both of them, the `node-gyp` fails either inside by app locally, or my push is rejected by Heroku when I try to deploy. So I am kinda stuck with `opusscript`.

Comment: If you are trying to run `npm install` to install the packages on Heroku, you wouldn't be able to so. Instead, do them locally so that they are listed inside on your `package.json`. Heroku reads for all dependencies via your `package.json` file.
Also check out these Heroku buildpacks that may help: 
[FFmpeg](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest),
[Opus](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/dubsmash/heroku-buildpack-opus),
[LibOpus](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/crazycatz00/heroku-buildpack-libopus)

Comment: I always install new packages using `npm install package-name --save` to ensure they are listed inside the `package.json`. However, thanks for those links, I have already added the FFMPEG buildpack but the second link is new to me.